# How implement this content iwith pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination

estoy intentando manejar un mensaje en mi tabla que sea de la siguiente manera, debe decir '1-25 de 50 registros' siendo 1 el primer elemento y 25 el ultimo de esa pagina , por lo que si voy a la siguiente debe decir '26-50 de 50 registros', el servicio retorna 2 propiedades ,uno es 'data' que es un arreglo de objetos y otro es 'pagination' que tiene 3 propiedades de esta manera {count:50,offset:25,limit:25}, intente de esta manera pero muestra '26-26

````
getDisplayedRange(): string {
   const start = this.paginationInfo.offset + 1;
   const end = Math.min(this.paginationInfo.offset + this.data.length, this.paginationInfo.count);
   return `${start}-${end} de ${this.paginationInfo.count} registros`;
 }
```, estoy haciendo en angular
````